# Meaning of '2' in '2 Windsor Terrace'

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the book [The death of the heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Heart), there is house named *2 Windsor Terrace*.

What is the meaning of the number 2 there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a street with many houses the houses are usually identified by a number. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering) for discussion of the practices in different countries around the world. The number is used  to identify the house for postal deliveries and for administrative purposes such as property taxes and utility supply.

This sounds like a UK address, and I guess that the author is painting a picture of very ordinary street. Terraces usually have lots of quite small houses joined together in a row. Windsor is a quite up-market town (where Her Majesty has her castle) but this street is almost certainly not in Windsor, it is named after the nice town; street names are often chosen to make an ordinary street sound more special.

It is very common for streets in the UK to have the even house numbers on one side of the road, and the odd numbers on the other. So number 2, Windsor Terrace is probably the first house in a row of houses in an undistinguished street.

Comment: Oh, Terraces are small houses in real world? In this book, 2 Windsor Terrace is depicted as whelthy house in Regent's Park.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regency_architecture) Maybe it's fictional place I think.

Comment: Ah, well I live in tiny terraced house, very common in London, there are hundreds of such in my neighbourhood. However, you're right there are the very up-market terraces, such as the one near Regent's Park. So, I jumped to a mistaken conclusion about the author's intention. The Royal Crescent in Bath is another famous example of a very "posh" terrace. Apologies for misleading you.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of the house on the street. [Windsor Terrace is in London](https://www.google.com/maps/place/2+Windsor+Terrace,+Hoxton,+London,+UK/@51.5292927,-0.0958082,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48761ca760d3146f:0x2b4bc5d3f257b65c!8m2!3d51.5292894!4d-0.0936195), the houses are numbered 2, 4, 6... on one side of the street, and 1, 3, 5... on the other side.

[Naming and numbering of streets and buildings](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/services/environment-and-planning/planning/planning-applications/submitting-planning-applications/Pages/Naming-and-numbering-of-streets-and-buildings.aspx) at the City of London website.